# PHP MySQL Select values with range

Tags: php, mysql

I just trying to select range of values from my mysql.

So my function search works fine for one value like this:

```
    if (!empty($szukaj['cena'])) {
        $select->where(['cena' => $szukaj['cena']]);
    }
```

I try something like this - where 'cena1' is minimal value and 'cena2' is maximum value.

```
    if (!empty($szukaj['cena'])) {
        $select->where(range(['cena1',cena2'=> $szukaj['cena']]);
    }
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: What ORM are you using?

Comment: cena2 is missing a starting single-quote.